# Groovy API Response JSON object assertion

Tags: java, json, groovy

API Response

```
[Data:[DuplicateInvoiceReference:null, RequestID:null], Error:[[Code:API.INV.005, Description:Invoice Reference is null or empty]], 
Status:3, Warning:null]
```

I'm going to asset the Error Object, below is my code

```
def responseData = jsonSlurper.parseText(responseBody)
assert responseData.Error.Description == "Invoice Reference is null or empty"
```

but I received assertion failed

```
assert responseData.Error.Description == "Invoice Reference is null or empty"
       |            |     |           |
       |            |     |           false
       |            |     [Invoice Reference is null or empty]
       |            [[Code:API.INV.005, Description:Invoice Reference is null or empty]]
       [Data:[DuplicateInvoiceReference:null, RequestID:null], Error:[[Code:API.INV.005, Description:Invoice Reference is null or empty]], Status:3, Warning:null]
```

Please clarify the issues in the assertion part?

Comment: Please include the output of `responseData.Error.Description.class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading `Description` as though `Error` were a map. It is a list.

You should be having

```
assert responseData.Error[0].Description == "Invoice Reference is null or empty"
```

You need to read `Description` off the first element of `responseData.Error`